# Is it possible to change text console (VT, framebuffer) foreground color?

Tags: customization, colors, text-mode, framebuffer

I tried `setterm -foreground green` but any action resets the color back to white.
Also, switching black and white seems like a nice option for e-paper (e-ink) screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the option `-store` to make it stick.

[image]